# How to auto populate the currency value into the custom object while creating record using related list button

Tags: apex, urlhacking, currency

I have opportunity car set (custom object , Master object) which has a related list in that "service"(custom object,child object). In service there is a **standard** picklist field called "**Currency**".

It has two values.

1. EUR-Euro
2. DZD-Algerian Dinar

I need to populate the currency field value as "DZD-Algerian Dinar" in service object if Opportunity Car set "country code"(Custom field) equals to DZ.
Like this according to the country code, currency field value needs to get populated.

I am able to populate a text field and lookup field using below code. But i am unable to populate the currency field

Example:

```
/a0B/e?CF00NA0000005JzZX={!ObjectMaster__c.Name}
 &CF00NA0000005JzZX_lkid={!ObjectMaster__c.Id}
 &00NF00000082xeJ={!ObjectMaster__c.TextField__c}
 &retURL=/{!ObjectMaster__c.Id}
```

Please help me out!!! Thanks in advance !!

Comment: hmm.. you need to inspect the currency field and check the name of the field. it will be looks like `CF00NA0000005JzZX_lkid`. Just mouse over your currency field click right side and inspect element. You can see and selectoption. you need use that selectlist Id.

Comment: While inspecting the element am getting the below  "<label for="CurrencyIsoCode"><span class="assistiveText">*</span>Currency</label>"

Comment: Am not getting any id@Ratan

Comment: when I inspect a currencyIsoCode field on an Edit page - the id = `CurrencyIsoCode`

Comment: Yes the id is "CurrencyIsoCode"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like **[@Cropedy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2602/cropredy)** said you just need to add `CurrencyIsoCode` in url as

```
&CurrencyIsoCode=DZD
```

DZD can be your picklist value. there will a chance where picklist label and value is not same.

Inspect element the picklist and check the correct value